# Spring Tool Suite 4 Console Color issue

Tags: console, highlight, spring-tools-4

I'm developing a Spring Boot application with Spring Tools Suite 4. I don't know why but most of the log messages are highlighted in red color. Only the spring boot logo has a normal color highlighting.

I have the following setup:

- STS-4.2.2
- Maven 3.6.1
- `spring.output.ansi.enabled=always`
- Windows 7 with an older powershell version (if that even matters)
- Eclipse console settings are standard (only syserr should create red events).

Did I miss something? Thanks for your help

Comment: I tried Win7 (64bit) with a fresh nightly CI build of the upcoming version STS 4.3.0 on Eclipse 4.12 using a 64bit JDK (1.8.0_211) and the console showed the right nice ansi coloring for me when I started a boot app using the boot dashboard (without any additional settings). Anything different from your setup?

Comment: @MartinLippert Thanks for your response. I found the issue (see the answer below). Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I expected standard Spring Boot Logging to be in place (which is Logback). But this library was not included. So by adding this dependency, everything works like a charm.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
   <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
</dependency>
```